# Remove related questions from the middle of the page

Tags: script, userstyle, related

Stack Exchange graduated the [test of moving the related questions section in the middle of the secreen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423143/a-b-testing-related-questions-within-the-answers-list-testing-has-concluded).

[image: Image from the announcement of the test showing "Related questions" in the middle of the page after the question]

This section rarely provides actually relevant questions and it serves as a big distraction in most cases.

The userstyle removes it from the middle of the screen by directly hiding it. When Related Questions show in the right panel, the old behaviour is preserved and the section is not hidden.

```html
/* ==UserStyle==
@name         Stack Exchange remove related 
@description  Removes the related section
@namespace    https://github.com/PurpleMagick/
@version      1
@author       VLAZ
@contributor  LunarWatcher 
@license      MIT
==/UserStyle== */

@-moz-document domain("stackoverflow.com"), domain("superuser.com"), domain("serverfault.com"), domain("askubuntu.com"), domain("stackapps.com"), domain("mathoverflow.net"), domain("stackexchange.com") {
#inline_related_var_a_less, #inline_related_see_more, #inline_related_see_less {
    display: none !important;
}
}
```

[See the code on GitHub](https://github.com/PurpleMagick/userstyles/blob/main/stackoverflow/hide-related-questions.user.css) ([Direct installation](https://github.com/PurpleMagick/userstyles/raw/main/stackoverflow/hide-related-questions.user.css))

Comment: This is great. Thank you. Those questions are not even remotely relevant most of the times and removing them should be the official direction, but until then this script would be really helpful.